# Is a problem being undecidable equivalent to saying it's in NP-hard?

Tags: np-hard

I understand how to prove that the halting problem is undecidable. However, I'm confused as to why it is NP-hard. Is a problem being undecidable equivalent to saying it's in NP-hard?

Answer (score 0):

A problem is said to be "NP-hard" if there is a poly-time reduction from every NP problem to it.

The halting problem is indeed NP-hard, because of the following reason:

Let L be an NP problem, since L is in NP, it is decidable - thus there is a deterministic turing machine that decides L, denote it as M. Now we can create M', that simulates M and halts i.f.f M accepts x (where x is the input). And the result of the reduction on input x is (M', x).

Denote the reduction as R and indeed x is in L i.f.f R(x) is in H.

(M(x) = 1 => M'(x) halts => (M', x) is in H.
M(x) = 0 => M'(x) doesn't halt => (M', x) is not in H)

Why is the reduction polynomial? the size of the description of M may be very large, but it's FIXED. So it takes constant time to create M' (one can look at it as M' being "hardcoded" in R), so the reduction is linear and so polynomial.

Because of the transitivity of reduction (i.e., if there is a (polynomial/ computational) reduction from L1 to L2 and from L2 to L3 (MUST BE SAME REDUCTION TYPE!) there is a reduction from L1 to L3) it is enough to show a reduction from a known NP-hard problem to a new problem to prove that the new problem is NP-hard, and that's the common way to do so. In this example, it was convenient to prove directly from the definiton.

As of your other question, the answer is no. there exists an undecidable problem which is not NP-hard. 
You can see a proof here: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642726/are-all-undecidable-problems-np-hard

Note that if P=NP, every problem (except for the trivial sets) is NP-hard. so The proof assumes P != NP.